# Folland Real Analysis Chapter 7 Exercise 12

Tags: real-analysis

The Question is:
Let $X = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{d}$ where $\mathbb{R}_{d}$ denotes $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology. If $f$ is a function on $X$, let $f^{y}(x) = f(x, y)$. Prove that $f \in C_{c}(X)$ iff $f^{y} \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f^{y} = 0$ for all but finitely many $y$.

I do not quite understand how can it be for some $y$ such that $f^{y}$ not equal to $0$. Suppose that $f(x_0, y_0) = 1$, then if $f$ continuous, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0, y_0)$ such that $f(U) \subset$ a neighborhood of $1$. But since everything neighborhood is of the form $V \times \mathbb{R}$ because of discrete topology, this means that $f(U) > 0$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and for some $x \in V$, which is contradictory to the condition that $f^y = 0$ for all but finitely many $y$. Any thoughts? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you are confusing the discrete and indiscrete topologies. The latter only has $\emptyset$ and the whole space as open sets, whereas all sets are open in the discrete case. So your basis of open sets is not right. I think once you use the correct definition the "for all but finitely many $y$" becomes a consequence of the types of compact sets in discrete topologies.

Comment: Yeah I think I made a mistake there and I figured it out. Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW how do I change the status to be ''solved''?

Comment: @AndrewLiu: You can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys... So obviously I mistook discrete topology for trivial topology. Since it is discrete topology, every y in R is an open set, so that only finitely many can have f^y \neq 0 or else the support is not compact.